# How to display Meteor.user() profile data in the view

Tags: meteor

*I imagine this has to be an elementary issue however I've been struggling through this for too long. I'm relatively new to Meteor.*

I've viewed the documentation for the Meteor.user() (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) and can see how additional information is added to the user.profile. I.e.,

```
//JS file
Meteor.users.insert({
    username: 'admin',
    profile: {
                first_name: 'Clark',
                last_name: 'Kent'
    },

});
```

How then do I display the profile information in the view template? I can access the user object via the view and web console (`Meteor.user()`) however I cannot access the object details.

My initial thoughts were that I could load the following in my handlebar templates but they do not work:

```
// HTML view
{{Meteor.user().username}}
{{Meteor.user().profile.first_name}}
{{Meteor.user().profile.last_name}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply `{{currentUser.profile.first_name}}` would do it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your insert is correct.

But to show the information like the first name you have to provide a helper function.

Your html-template:

```
<template name="user">
  <p>{{firstName}}</p>
</template>
```

Your js-code:

```
Template.user.helpers({
  firstName: function() {
    return Meteor.user().profile.first_name;
  }
});
```

You can additionaly wrap the user template with the {{currentUser}} helper to be sure there is a user.

```
{{#if currentUser}} 
  {{> user}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Ahh. Sorry for the incredibly late reply. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to define a proxy helper for different attributes of objects nested in `{{currentUser}}`, you can do the following purely in your template:

```
{{#with currentUser}}
    {{#with profile}}
        {{first_name}}
    {{/with}}
{{/with}}
```

*Updated to reflect comment suggestion.*

Answer (score 7):

In your templates, you'll want to use `{{currentUser}}` instead of `{{Meteor.user()}}`.

[Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
{{#with userDetails}}
   First name:-{{this.first_name}}
   Last name:- {{this.last_name}}
{{/with}}

 //jsSide
 userDetails(){
   return Meteor.user();
 }
```